# Star Wars Lego build ID help

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I have an old set built that for the life of me I cannot identify. It has been collecting dust for a number of years. I was able to identify one of the others (Jek-14's Stealth Starfighter) but this one isn't even similar to everything I have seen so far.

It has been played with by my two sons (21 and 7) so may not be exactly accurate, but the bones of it have to have been made from instructions.

Trying to find the build instructions to remake it the way it was intended. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is from [75025: Jedi Defender-class Cruiser](https://brickset.com/sets/75025-1/Jedi-Defender-class-Cruiser)
[image: 75025]

keypart: [Dark Red Wedge, Plate 4 x 4 Cut Corner](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30503&colorID=59&in=A)